# Beamer Font Size for Footer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, fontsize

How can I change the font size of the footer in Beamer without modifying the font of the title (on the title page)? Also, when I try to change the title's font with `\title{\fontsize{20}{25} My Title}` it doesn't seem to work. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to change the font for all the elements in the footline of just fot the title in the footline?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina How do I change the font for all the elements in the footline? Because for the title I followed Marco's advice and used `\title[\fontsize{10}{15}\fontselect My Title]{etc}`, which changes the font size for the title.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina I think I figured it out: I just have to use instead of `\title` `\author` with the same type of argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the command `\selectfont` after `fontsize`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\title[My Title]{ \fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont My Title} 
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\frame{a frame}
\end{document}
```

Detailed information are documented in the [Docmentation of LaTeX font commands](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fntguide)

**EDIT**: Use the theme `AnnArbor` and the optional argument of `\title`.

Comment: Thanks, Marco. It makes sense. But I still have no idea if it's possible to change separately the footer's font size. I use AnnArbor theme, and when I modify the size of the font, the footer is altered too and I get several Warnings and an Overfull `\hbox`.

Comment: Awesome! I don't get any errors now. Cheers!

Answer (score 15):

You can change the font for all the elements in the footline simply by setting the footline font using

```
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=<size>}
```

A little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\title[Short title]{Long}
\author[Short author]{Long}
\institute[Short inst.]{Long}

\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if the chosen font is too big, the results obtained won't be very pleasing (try using `\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont` in my example code above). In this case, you will have to change the `footline` template. In the following example I made some changes in the spacing between the date and the page number and after the page number, to have a footline with a font size of `10pt`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\title[Short title]{Long title}
\author[Short author]{Long author}
\institute[Short inst.]{Long institute}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{1em}% original: 2ex
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}% original: 2ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for your time and this useful tip.

Comment: Regarding `\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}`, the first number (i.e. `9`) changes the font size; what does the second number (`11`) make?

Comment: You can also use `\setbeamerfont{footline}{size = \footnotesize}`.

Comment: Is there a way to change the font size of the progression bar too? I mean those circles and text above them on the header of the slide which show the progression of the presentation.