# How to reduce the font size of the title displayed in Warsaw's theme footer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, fontsize, footer

My document's title doesn't fit the Warsaw's theme footline. I've read [how to make a two-lined title in the footline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236607/two-line-title-in-footline-of-warsaw-theme) but what I really wanted was to simply reduce the font size displayed in the footline in Warsaw theme.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{Thank you for helping me out!}

\author{Vitor Taira Yi}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What about the solutions in [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26848/beamer-font-size-for-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26848/beamer-font-size-for-footer) (particularly the `\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=<size>}` one)?